# Want to Populate all fields of a custom object which is having a lookup relation to another custom object

Tags: data-loader, trigger

Currently, i am building a relationship between several objects so that from one object i can populate all relevant information. These relationships are populated through custom report type. So, currently it is like

Survey_Response__C(Detail)>Survey__C (Master)>Call_Report__C (Lookup relationship to survey)>Contact (Lookup relationship to call report)

However, from contact i want to refer to all fields of another custom object called customer brand which is a detail record and Contact Is its master.

So, i have made a lookup relationship to Survey__C from Customer_brand__C and then i am populating the Salesforce ID of survey through formula field. (Basic Aim is to populate Customer brand ID for surveys even though earlier they do not have any relation)

However, i want to populate the survey name for all old data present in the org automatically through some trigger (As we are just testing one data from customer brand with lookup to survey and then populating its ID through formula).

Could you please help in starting from trigger, or is there any other way that we can extract data from data loader (Nested query also doesn't wok)

Comment: Whether via a script or trigger, as I understand your data model there are many Survey__C per Contact and many Customer_Brand__C per Contact. Do you have an algorithm based on additional factors to select the correct Customer_Brand__C to relate to a Survey__C?

Comment: @ keith : Yes, you are right. There are many surveys per contact and many customer brand per contact. Also, each survey is attached to one template which is always based on brand name (Template is a lookup in survey and for your reference customer brand is formed with contact and brand object where contact is master and brand is lookup). So, i think to check if the template name somehow matches with customer brand of a contact and if the contact is present in that survey, then compare them against the contact in customer brand object and try to populate.

Comment: @ Keith : If we can use script or soql query somehow to populate all data as i know, nested query is not working in data loader and i am trying to query related list records.

Comment: Seems the below code would work, however is there any other way if we can use just SOQL query in data loader? The basic aim remains same : Extract surveys with survey responses with contact and then customer brand Ids

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example of how you might do this using Apex code - you understand your data model, I don't. The code could be run multiple times in the Developer Console.

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
Survey__c surveys = [
        select Id, Template__r.Name
        from Survey__c
        where Customer_Brand__c == null
        limit 500
        ];
for (Survey__c s : surveys) {
    names(s.Template__r.Name);
}
Map<String, Id> namesToIds = new Map<String, Id>();
for (Customer_Brand__c b : [
        select Id, Name
        from Customer_Brand__c
        where Name in :names
        ]) {
    namesToIds.put(t.Name, t.Id);
}
for (Survey__c s : surveys) {
    s.Customer_Brand__c = namesToIds.get(s.Template__r.Name);
}
updated surveys;
```